# Python check udp port open

Tags: python, udp

I'm trying to check using Python 3.6 if a remote DNS server is listening on port 53 UDP.

This is what I tried:

```
def check_port(host, port):
    import socket
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.settimeout(1)
    try:
        result = s.connect_ex((host, port))
    except socket.gaierror:
        s.close()
        return 1
    s.close()
    return result  # 0 == Port is open
```

But I get 0 all the time even if the port is close.
Trying TCP using SOCK_STREAM works like a charm.

I also tried:

```
def check_port_udp(host, port):
    import socket
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.settimeout(1)
    try:
        s.sendto('ping'.encode(), (host, port))
        s.recvfrom(1024)
    except socket.timeout:
        s.close()
        print(1)
        return 1
    s.close()
    print(0)
    return 0  # 0 == Port is open
```

But I get 1 all then time even if the port it's open

Comment: What have you tried and what are the errors?

Comment: What options have you tried?

Comment: You may want to read this for reasons why UDP Scanning may fail completely: https://community.qualys.com/docs/DOC-1185

Comment: Thank Max, that article explained what I was missing.

Comment: In case of running your Python script on Linux you need to know that accessing TCP/UDP ports < 1024 is denied for all applications not running with root privileges by Linux kernel. Does it make a difference on running your Python script as root on Linux?

Answer (score 3):

I have had no luck using sockets for this purpose. The port response is based on the [target application](https://serverfault.com/a/193632) and is not standard like TCP.  I always use netcat for this:

```
import os
ip = "127.0.0.1"
port = "<some_udp_port>"
''' send to /dev/null 2>&1 to suppress terminal output '''
res = os.system("nc -vnzu "+ip+" "+port+" > /dev/null 2>&1")
if res == 0:
    print("port alive")
else:
    print("port dead")
```

This, obviously, requires running on a Linux system.  However if you have nmap installed on your Windows system you can try the following:

```
import os
ip = "127.0.0.1"
port = "<some_udp_port>"
res = os.system("ncat -vnzu "+ip+" "+port)
if res == 0:
    print("port alive")
else:
    print("port dead")
```

Answer (score 3):

Basic idea: send a DNS query to that port.If there is a response, the port is open.

```
import random
import socket
import struct


class SendDNSPkt:
    def __init__(self,url,serverIP,port=53):
        self.url=url
        self.serverIP = serverIP
        self.port=port
    def sendPkt(self):
        pkt=self._build_packet()
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        sock.settimeout(1)
        sock.sendto(bytes(pkt), (self.serverIP, self.port))
        data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
        sock.close()
        return data

    def _build_packet(self):
        randint = random.randint(0, 65535)
        packet = struct.pack(">H", randint)  # Query Ids (Just 1 for now)
        packet += struct.pack(">H", 0x0100)  # Flags
        packet += struct.pack(">H", 1)  # Questions
        packet += struct.pack(">H", 0)  # Answers
        packet += struct.pack(">H", 0)  # Authorities
        packet += struct.pack(">H", 0)  # Additional
        split_url = self.url.split(".")
        for part in split_url:
            packet += struct.pack("B", len(part))
            for s in part:
                packet += struct.pack('c',s.encode())
        packet += struct.pack("B", 0)  # End of String
        packet += struct.pack(">H", 1)  # Query Type
        packet += struct.pack(">H", 1)  # Query Class
        return packet

def checkDNSPortOpen():
    # replace 8.8.8.8 with your server IP!
    s = SendDNSPkt('www.google.com', '8.8.8.8')
    portOpen = False
    for _ in range(5): # udp is unreliable.Packet loss may occur
        try:
            s.sendPkt()
            portOpen = True
            break
        except socket.timeout:
            pass
    if portOpen:
        print('port open!')
    else:
        print('port closed!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    checkDNSPortOpen()
```

Inspired by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24814044/having-trouble-building-a-dns-packet-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

The following code can help you in scanning for port 53/udp :

```
from socket import *
import sys, time
from datetime import datetime

host = ''
ports = [53]

def scan_host(host, port, r_code = 1) : 
    try : 
        s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
        code = s.connect_ex((host, port))
        if code == 0 : 
            r_code = code
        s.close()
    except Exception, e : 
        pass
    return r_code

try : 
    host = raw_input("[*] Enter Target Host Address :  ")
except KeyBoardInterrupt : 
    sys.exit(1)

hostip = gethostbyname(host)

for port in ports : 
    try : 
        response = scan_host(host, port)
        if response == 0 : 
            print("[*] Port %d: Open" % (port))
    except Exception, e : 
        pass
```

You can refer to [this example](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/code-snippets-source-code/port-scanner-in-python) for further exploration on port scanning.

Comment: I try this already and you get '0' all the time even if the port it's not open:

Comment: can you please explain which part of the code makes it udp and not tcp connection ?

Comment: @UddhavMishra - it's `SOCK_DGRAM` param. It sends User Datagram (thus UDProtocol) ;)

Answer (score 0):

first

yum install -y nmap-ncat

and then

```py
import os
ip = "127.0.0.1"
port = "<some_udp_port>"
''' send to /dev/null 2>&1 to suppress terminal output '''
res = os.system("nc -vnzu "+ip+" "+port+" > /dev/null 2>&1")
if res == 0:
    print("port alive")
else:
    print("port dead")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The following code is adapted from [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-simple-port-scanner-with-sockets/) which checks TCP ports :

```
# Python code for simple UDP port scanning
#
import socket

START_PORT = 50000
END_PORT = START_PORT + 4
PRINT_FREE_PORTS = True

# get host ip-address
ip = socket.gethostbyname (socket.gethostname())

# loop through ports
for port in range(START_PORT, END_PORT+1):
    try:
        # create a new socket
        serv = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        # bind to new socket
        serv.bind((ip, port))
        # print free port number
        if PRINT_FREE_PORTS:
            print('       port :',port)
    except:
        # print open port number
        print('[OPEN] port :',port)
    # close connection
    serv.close()
```